# mysql query INSERT INTO in a conditional statements (case if/else)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out to insert into using conditional statements in mysql like [INSERT INTO in a CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996591/insert-into-in-a-case-statement)

```
SET @foo = 1
SELECT (CASE WHEN 1 THEN (
  INSERT INTO table1 (`id`, `column`) VALUE (1, 'a');
  SET @bar = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
  UPDATE table2 SET c1 = @foo WHERE c2 = @bar
) END)
```

I'm using `case` as recommended by [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

But when I try that I keep getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO ForgeRock (`id`, `productName`, `description`) VALUE (4, 'a','b') ) END)' at line 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/22063

So I'm trying to go with the if/else approach...

```
SELECT IF(1,(INSERT INTO ForgeRock (`id`, `productName`, `description`) VALUE (4, 'a','b')),0)
```

But that gives the same error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO ForgeRock (`id`, `productName`, `description`) VALUE (4, 'a','b')),0)' at line 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/22081

So I'm assuming this is not possible to do in mysql? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13681306/1267259
(OP is however not getting the same error?)

As I was writing this question I found [Using IF ELSE statement based on Count to execute different Insert statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072140/using-if-else-statement-based-on-count-to-execute-different-insert-statements)
Is the only way to do this by using procedure?

Comment: Yes,flow control statements can only be done in stored programs in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the difference between [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

One option you can implement is to use a FUNCTION ([13.1.12 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)):

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `insert_new_value` (`p_foo` INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS TINYINT(1)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  /*
  INSERT INTO table1 (`id`, `column`) VALUE (1, 'a');
  SET @bar = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
  -- UPDATE table2 SET c1 = @foo WHERE c2 = @bar;
  UPDATE table2 SET c1 = `p_foo` WHERE c2 = @bar;
  */
  INSERT INTO `ForgeRock`
  (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
  VALUES
  (4, 'a', 'b');
  RETURN 1;
END//

DELIMITER ;

SET @foo := 1;
-- You can also use CASE expression.
SELECT IF(1, `insert_new_value`(@foo), 0) INTO @`return_value`;

/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e04e68/1)</kbd>

Comment: Function/procedure are both too complicated for my case but +1 and accepted as a good example of how to do it.